# On a xbox 360, can wireless be turned off?

Tags: xbox-360

I would like to know if I can turn off WiFi on an Xbox 360.

Thanks

Comment: Does unplugging the antenna count?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, there are a few possibilities.

1. If your 360 is old enough, it needs a USB-enabled wifi adapter. Unplugging this is effectively "turning the wifi off".
2. If you have a newer model 360 (Slim), the adapter is built-in to the hardware, and cannot be turned off. You can have it forget networks, but it will always be on.

Source: [This](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_support/xbox_360_support/f/7/t/444662.aspx) and previous experience.